# echo command adds a lof of spaces to a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

Here is my script:

```
set "rec1=01%YYYYMMDD%xxxxxx xxxxxxx0935"
set "rec2=99%YYYYMMDD%             000000000000000000000000000000000000000935"

echo %rec1%>X:\BUBK_test.txt                                            
echo %rec2%>>X:\BUBK_test.txt`
```

First picture shows what I see on the console window, the second is a file display in hex.

[image: Here is what I see on the console window]

[image: And when I look on the file in the hex mode I see a lot of spaces after "935" characters.]

Any ideas what happened?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your batch file contains a ton of extra spaces at the end of the `echo` command:

```
echo %rec1%>X:\BUBK_test.txt                                            
REM                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you remove those, your output file should get shorter as well.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. Without extra spaces it is working now!